# How to find the normal vector to a parametrized surface in order to find the flux?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to find the flux of $F = (x, y, z)^T$ through the surface $A = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid 0 \leq z \leq 1 - x^2 - y^2\}$. To my knowledge the surface can be broken up to parts $A_1 = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid z = 0, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ and $ A_2 = \{(x, y ,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 - z\}$. Right now I am struggling with 1.) finding normal vector to $A_2$ 2.) calculating the corresponding flux. The hint I have been given is that $A_2$ should be parametrized as the plot of a function. The issue is that I don't know how to apply the hint. Do we want to define $f(x, y) = 1 - x^2 - y^2$ and then, something? How does this help us to find the normal vector for $\int\int_{A_2}F \cdot n dS$?

Moreover, to my knowledge the normal vector for $A_1$ is $-k$, so that $F \cdot (-k) = -z$. Then won't the flox through $A_1$ be zero, as $\int\int_{A_a}F \cdot n dS = \int\int_{A_1}-zdS$?

Comment: The normal vector for a surface parameterized $(x,y,f(x,y))$ is always $(f_x,f_y,-1)$ (this includes the Jacobian, do not normalize it)

Comment: The given surface $A$ seems to be missing a bound on $z$.

Comment: @MathLover Bound for $z$ is included in $0 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z \leq 1$.

Comment: Two paraboloid surfaces $x^2+y^2 = - z$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1 - z$ never intersect.

Comment: Just saw your edit. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cartesian coordinates, the surface can be parametrized as $z = f(x,y) = 1 - x^2 - y^2, 0 \leq z \leq 1$. The outward normal vector to the surface is then $(-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, -\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, 1) = (2x, 2y, 1)$. Note the projection of the surface in $XY$ plane is $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$

So the surface integral is $ \ \displaystyle \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} \vec F \cdot (2x, 2y, 1) \ dx \ dy$

Another way to calculate flux will be to close the surface with unit disk at $z = 0$ and apply divergence theorem. You have to then subtract the flux through the disk to find flux through the paraboloid surface (by the way, in this case, the flux through the disk at $z = 0$ is zero).

Comment: This is probably an elementary question, but we can readily substitute the polar coordinates for the integral you wrote, where $r \in [0, 1], \theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, and x, y and z are substituted accordingly?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Pls add Jacobian $r$.

Comment: do you happen to know why I get the right answer ($3\pi/2$) if I first calculate everything symbolically with $x, y, z$, and only at integration do I convert to polar coordinates. Whereas if I first convert to polar coordinates $x = r\cos(\theta), y = r\sin(\theta), z = 1 - r^2$, then find the normal vector with partials w.r.t. $r, \theta$, I get a differing answer?

Comment: It should of course work. Do you get the normal vector $(2r^2 \cos \theta, 2r^2 \sin\theta, r)$? If not, you are doing a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Actually I do get just that normal vector. Then isn't the dot product with the vector field $F$ equal to: $-r^4 + 2r^3 + r^2$? Integrating that where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi], r \in [0, 1]$ did not yield $3\pi/2$.